# Python run GUI while serial reader is running

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, pyserial

I have to build an application that maintains a GUI while a serial reader is constantly running in the background. The serial reader updates variables that i need to show on my GUI. So far i have this:

```
# These variables are updated by the reader.
var1 = 0
var2 = 0
var3 = 0

#Serial reader
def readserial(self):
ser = serial.Serial(port='COM4', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
while 1:
    b = ser.readline()
    if b.strip():
        #Function to set variables var1,var2,var3
        handle_input(b.decode('utf-8'))

#Simple GUI to show the variables updating live
root = Tk()
root.title("A simple GUI")

gui_var1 = IntVar()
gui_var1.set(var1)

gui_var2 = IntVar()
gui_var2.set(var2)

gui_var3 = IntVar()
gui_var3.set(var3)

root.label = Label(root, text="My Gui")
root.label.pack()

root.label1 = Label(root, textvariable=gui_var1)
root.label1.pack()

root.label2 = Label(root, textvariable=gui_var2)
root.label2.pack()

root.label3 = Label(root, textvariable=gui_var3)
root.label3.pack()

root.close_button = Button(root, text="Close", command=root.quit)
root.close_button.pack()

#Start GUI and Serial
root.mainloop()
readserial()
```

As it is now my gui opens and as soon as i close it the serial starts reading.

Comment: are you aware that `mainloop()` doesn't return until the root window is destroyed?

Comment: now you have to loops - `while 1` and `mainloop`. They have to work at the same time. You can user `threading` module to run `while 1` in separated thread. Or `root.after(miliseconds, function_name)` to run `ser.readline() ...` periodicaly (without `while 1`). `after` may not work if `readline` blocks program waiting for data.

Comment: I am aware that i'm dealing with two loops here. I guess my question can be summarized to "How do i make these two loops run at the same time?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `root.after(miliseconds, function_name_without_brackets)` to run function `readserial` periodically - without `while 1`.

Tested on Linux with virtual COM ports `/dev/pts/5`, `/dev/pts/6`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial 

# --- functions ---

def readserial():
    b = ser.readline()
    if b.strip():
         label['text'] = b.decode('utf-8').strip()
    # run again after 100ms (mainloop will do it)
    root.after(100, readserial)

# --- main ---

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM4', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
#ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/pts/6', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=root.destroy)
button.pack()

# run readserial first time after 100ms (mainloop will do it)
root.after(100, readserial)

# start GUI
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I cannnot do it like this, the serial read function needs to run uninterrupted or the readings that are received are incomplete.

Comment: Of course you can do it this way. The serial port buffers data until you are ready to read it. If the buffer fills up to quickly then you might lose data, the solution is to read from the serial port more often.